# google sheets- How to query multiple columns from a different sheet without having it combine the first column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a query that pulls specific ranges of columns from a different sheet. It is combining the top two rows. Any way to string together multiple ranges of columns from a different sheet and not combine the top row? thanks

example Query ( {'mainview'!, A1:L36, 'mainview'!n1:N36}) this does not work

First column not combined with second.

Comment: I'm voting to delete this as caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to combine two ranges:

```
={mainview!A1:L36,mainview!N1:N36}
```